# Context for multiple requests in Django

Tags: python, django, request

I have a Django app where in some of the pages we do multiple GET request, because for example they fetch resources from two different apps.

Every user has a set of permissions and the permissions are re-computed per each request, but this is unnecessary because the permissions are going to be the same for the whole page.

Is there something like a context that can last for more than one request, ideally for a view for example?

Comment: I dont know if this can be done, but one work around could be, send in a unique IDentifier, like a timestamp or something in the context, and everytime the requests come in, cache the permissions with this identifier, and send the response from the cache object.

Comment: Be careful of premature optimisation. Is calculating the permissions per-request really causing a noticeable slow-down?

Comment: Storing intermediary data like that is kinda what server-side sessions are for, but, as Alasdair rightly says, unless it's a very expensive computation, just do it per-request. A piece of custom middleware is a good place for that sort of thing.

Comment: It's not much of an attempt of optimization but rather a simplification..The problem is that I get the permissions based on an url that fetches an object, but doing it for some of the gets in the same page is a lot harder.

If I could cache that I could avoid some extra computation and keep the code simple while having the same result..

Comment: @andrea_crotti It might help to include a more detailed explanation of the way you're currently doing this, ideally including some of the code you're currently using. At the moment it's a little too vague to give any kind of useful answer.

Comment: A session is not good because this thing I need can change all the time basically, depending on where the user go in the website.

Anyway I probably found another solution and it seems there is no real easy fix for this, so I'll just do it per each request and be done with it, or check again if the performances are really bad..Thanks